# Moment says invalid date

Tags: jquery, momentjs

I have a span that uses a class `fromNow` to tell moment to change the date between the span tags to change into a 'time ago' format. It works flawlessly, but only when there is one span.

If I add a 2nd span, it says `Invalid date`.

Here's the https://jsfiddle.net/xyh0Lmpp/3/ where it can be seen not working, why does it say `Invalid date` when there are two classes, but works with one?

What I want to do is make it so all spans with the class `fromNow` are changed to the 'time ago' format, and if it fails to do so, just show the date between the span tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have multiple `span` with the `fromNow` class your `$('.fromNow')` selector matches all of them (see [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)). You can use [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to loop each matched element.

For the moment part, as [`moment(String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) docs says:

> When creating a moment from a string, we first check if the string matches known [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats, we then check if the string matches the [RFC 2822 Date time](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.3) format before dropping to the fall back of `new Date(string)` if a known format is not found.

**Warning:** Browser support for parsing strings [is inconsistent](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html). Because there is no specification on which formats should be supported, what works in some browsers will not work in other browsers.

> 

For consistent results parsing anything other than ISO 8601 strings, you should use [String + Format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

So in your case, you can use [`moment(String, String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) using `'MMM DD, YYYY h:mm A'` as format parameter. This will work across browser, it will not show Deprecation Warning in console and it will not show `Invalid Date`.

Here a live sample:

```js
var then = $('.fromNow');

update = function() {
  // Loop each element matched by class selector
  then.each(function(){
    // Create jQuery element for current element
    $elem = $(this);
    // Parse text using moment, then format relative time
    $elem.html(moment($elem.text(), 'MMM DD, YYYY h:mm A').fromNow());
  });
}
update();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js"></script>

<span class="fromNow">March 16, 2018 6:54 PM</span>
<span class="fromNow">March 16, 2018 5:54 PM</span>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly, I'm still kinda new to JavaScript.